# Efficient code for imputation of negative values using pyspark

Tags: pyspark, apache-spark-sql, mode, imputation

I am working on a data set which contains item wise- date wise information about the quantity sold of that particular item. However, there are some negative values in the ' quantity sold' column which I intend to impute. The logic used here would be to replace such negative values with the mode of the quantity sold for each item at date level. I have already computed the count of each distinct value of the quantity sold and obtained the maximum quantity sold of a particular item on each given date. However I am unable to find a function that would replace the negative values with the max qty sold for each item* date combination. I am relatively newer to pyspark. Which would be best approach to use in this case?

Comment: Welcome to SO! Maybe you could add some example data (input data and expected result)?

Answer (score 0):

Based on the limited information you provided , you can try something like this -

```
from pyspark import SparkContext
from pyspark.sql import SQLContext
from functools import reduce
import pyspark.sql.functions as F

from pyspark.sql import Window

sc = SparkContext.getOrCreate()
sql = SQLContext(sc)

input_list = [
   (1,10,"2019-11-07")
  ,(1,5,"2019-11-07")
  ,(1,5,"2019-11-07")
  ,(1,5,"2019-11-08")
  ,(1,6,"2019-11-08")
  ,(1,7,"2019-11-09")
  ,(1,7,"2019-11-09")
  ,(1,8,"2019-11-09")
  ,(1,8,"2019-11-09")
  ,(1,8,"2019-11-09")
  ,(1,-10,"2019-11-09")
  ,(2,10,"2019-11-07")
  ,(2,3,"2019-11-07")
  ,(2,9,"2019-11-07")
  ,(2,9,"2019-11-08")
  ,(2,-10,"2019-11-08")
  ,(2,5,"2019-11-09")
  ,(2,5,"2019-11-09")
  ,(2,2,"2019-11-09")
  ,(2,2,"2019-11-09")
  ,(2,2,"2019-11-09")
  ,(2,-10,"2019-11-09")
]


sparkDF = sql.createDataFrame(input_list,['product_id','sold_qty','date'])

sparkDF = sparkDF.withColumn('date',F.to_date(F.col('date'), 'yyyy-MM-dd'))
```

## Mode Implementation

```
#### Mode Implemention 
modeDF = sparkDF.groupBy('date', 'sold_qty')\
.agg(F.count(F.col('sold_qty')).alias('mode_count'))\
        .select(F.col('date'),F.col('sold_qty').alias('mode_sold_qty'),F.col('mode_count'))

window = Window.partitionBy("date").orderBy(F.desc("mode_count"))

#### Filtering out the most occurred value 
modeDF = modeDF\
    .withColumn('order', F.row_number().over(window))\
    .where(F.col('order') == 1)\
```

## Merging back with Base DataFrame to impute

```
sparkDF = sparkDF.join(modeDF
        ,sparkDF['date'] == modeDF['date']
        ,'inner'
    ).select(sparkDF['*'],modeDF['mode_sold_qty'],modeDF['mode_count'])


sparkDF = sparkDF.withColumn('imputed_sold_qty',F.when(F.col('sold_qty') < 0,F.col('mode_sold_qty'))\
                                        .otherwise(F.col('sold_qty')))


>>> sparkDF.show(100)
+----------+--------+----------+-------------+----------+----------------+      
|product_id|sold_qty|      date|mode_sold_qty|mode_count|imputed_sold_qty|
+----------+--------+----------+-------------+----------+----------------+
|         1|       7|2019-11-09|            2|         3|               7|
|         1|       7|2019-11-09|            2|         3|               7|
|         1|       8|2019-11-09|            2|         3|               8|
|         1|       8|2019-11-09|            2|         3|               8|
|         1|       8|2019-11-09|            2|         3|               8|
|         1|     -10|2019-11-09|            2|         3|               2|
|         2|       5|2019-11-09|            2|         3|               5|
|         2|       5|2019-11-09|            2|         3|               5|
|         2|       2|2019-11-09|            2|         3|               2|
|         2|       2|2019-11-09|            2|         3|               2|
|         2|       2|2019-11-09|            2|         3|               2|
|         2|     -10|2019-11-09|            2|         3|               2|
|         1|       5|2019-11-08|            9|         1|               5|
|         1|       6|2019-11-08|            9|         1|               6|
|         2|       9|2019-11-08|            9|         1|               9|
|         2|     -10|2019-11-08|            9|         1|               9|
|         1|      10|2019-11-07|            5|         2|              10|
|         1|       5|2019-11-07|            5|         2|               5|
|         1|       5|2019-11-07|            5|         2|               5|
|         2|      10|2019-11-07|            5|         2|              10|
|         2|       3|2019-11-07|            5|         2|               3|
|         2|       9|2019-11-07|            5|         2|               9|
+----------+--------+----------+-------------+----------+----------------+
```